# Auto populate lookup field based on a field value and show on page layout

Tags: process-builder, lookup

We have an 'Outcome' object with lookup to 'Volunteer hours' object. We created a Lookup field in the 'Outcome' object, that should be auto populated based on a field value and show on page layout. Is this possible using process builder and how?

Comment: please refer to https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/business_process_automation/units/process_builder its a good starting point and will help address your question

Comment: Are you going to create 'Outcome' records from 'Volunteer Hours' records?

Comment: that's correct all fields data except lookup field is read from online forms and into salesforce as newly created 'Outcome' records. The lookup field need to be read from salesforce itself based on a field value.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Process Builder for this. You have to write logic in Apex trigger to populate the field in the before Insert event.